# Cannot convert value of type 'Double?' to expected element type 'Array<Double>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'Double')

Tags: ios, swift

I have following var:

```
var coordinates: [[Double]]!
```

and I have a method that should append values:

```
func saveLocation() {

  locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
  mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    ProductData.shared.latitude = locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
    ProductData.shared.longitude = locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude

    coordinates = [
        [ProductData.shared.latitude, ProductData.shared.longitude]
    ]
}
```

in the line with coordinates = [...] I get the error Cannot convert value of type 'Double?' to expected element type 'Array.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'Double') and i have no idea why.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `!`

```
coordinates = [
    [ProductData.shared.latitude!, ProductData.shared.longitude!]
]
```

or `guard`

```
guard let lat = ProductData.shared.latitude , let lon = ProductData.shared.longitude else { return }

coordinates = [
    [lat,lon]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude and locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude are Optionals of Double because your location is Optional (see the "?" after it).

You should unwrap them like:

```swift
guard let coord = locationManager.location?.coordinate else { return }

coordinates = [
        [coord.latitude, coord.longitude]
    ]
```